# How much maximum electricity bill (units) can be generated on 2 KW connection?

Tags: power-supply, electricity, meter, units

I have got a bill of approx 14000 Units (50000 INR) for a month on 2kW connection. 
As per my analysis and understanding, it can't be more than 2 * 24 HRs * 30 Days = 1440. I think electricity meter is faulty and it has jumped 14000 Units in a month.

Demand shown in electricity meter is 0. As per my understanding If these much of units gets produced then demand will be near 10.

I have also asked the concerned department they were saying it is possible (but didn't make it clear) and electricity meter is working fine.

Am I missing something ? Plz help me understanding this .

Demand : The maximum demand value is the average from the instantaneous power (in kW or kVA) during a defined time interval, usually every 15 minutes (this time interval will depend on each country).

Comment: (1) A 2 kW (note lower case k for kilo, not K for kelvin) seems very low. In Ireland the standard connection is 14.5 kW (63 A). Your calculation is correct. Check your previous bills. Were the meters read or estimated? (2) What do you mean by "Demand shown in electricity meter is 0"? And "10"? Please update your question.

Comment: Had a look around.  From the currency mentioned, OP is in India.  I found references around the internet indicate that the "sanctioned load" is indeed 2kW for residential connections.  "Sanctioned" would be more along the lines of "allowed" rather than "rated." You can draw more power, but will apparently be charged a higher rate for your power if you go above 2kW.

Comment: @Transistor thanks for answering. Updated the question its kW and also defined demand.

Comment: @JRE thanks for answering . So If I draw more power than 2kW , meter should display demand >2kW around 10 kW. 
Actually I haven't used this much power the meter has  jumped. But I have to prove this so I need some facts .

Comment: My comment wasn't meant to explain your problem. It was simply additional information about your situation.  A 2kW limit is unusual in other parts of the world, so I added some background information.

Comment: As an Indian I'd like to add that if OP is saying his meter shows Max. Demand readings, it seems he is either industrial or commercial customer, in that case 2kW sectioned load thing may not apply, however it seems that OP would know if he had been drawing that much power, so looks like meter is cheating on OP. @Lovin, alternatively you can check by counting how many times impulse light blinks (it'll be on meter) why delivering known load, impulse per kWh ratio will be mentioned on meter.

Comment: Check previous electricity bills. (In the UK at least, may not apply to India) it is fairly normal for several bills to be based on estimates of electricity usage (to save the cost of sending someone to read the meter). If those estimates are wrong, there may be a substantial correction when the meter is finally read for real (hopefully after less than a year).

Comment: Nah, in India, we have bills strictly based on usage & not on assumptions

Comment: @Deep its domestic connection and average units for last 5 years is around 300-400 units / month, suddenly I got 14000 Units in a month. Electricity Department has changed the meter so I don't have the meter with me.

Comment: @BrianDrummond its usage bill not estimation.

Comment: They've changed it implies it was bad meter, your doubt was right then..